# Connecting a second external monitor via USB to USB-C to HDMI

Tags: windows-10, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I use a Lenovo T480 laptop for work and I bought two HP VH240a monitors to use while I am working from home. Both monitors work individually, but the laptop only has one HDMI port. To try and connect the second monitor, I am going from usb to usb-c to hdmi to the monitor, but cannot detect an input signal. If I try plugging the usb-c adapter into the usb-c/charging port, I can get the second monitor to display only if I disconnect the first monitor.

What can I do to get both monitors to display at the same time?

My system specs are:

- 8th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-8250U (1.60GHz, up to 3.40GHz with Turbo Boost, 6MB Cache)
- Operating System Windows 10 Home
- Graphics Integrated Intel® UHD Graphics 620 Memory 8GB
- DDR4 2400MHz
- Storage 512GB SSD PCIe
- Display 14.0" FHD (1920 x 1080) IPS, anti-glare, 250 nits
- Ports

  - 2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1** (one Always On)
  - 1 x USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C (Power Delivery, DisplayPort, Data transfer)
  - 1 x USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C / Intel Thunderbolt 3 (Power Delivery, DisplayPort, Data transfer)
- 4-in-1 SD card reader (SD, MMC, SDHC, SDXC)
- HDMI
- RJ45 Gigabit Ethernet
- Optional Smart card reader

Answer (score 1):

The official answer from the Lenovo forum is **NO**.

In order to use 2 monitors with your Lenovo T480 is to buy a [docking station](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/PD500174)

However although this is the official answer theres some users claiming that
you can use the USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C / Intel Thunderbolt 3 to use up to 2 monitors WITH AN STARDARD [USB TB3 HUB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P2WVQK4)
Possible connection setup =

Lenovo T480 HDMI out port --> HDMI to HDMI cable --> #1 VH240a HDMI in port

Lenovo T480 USB 3.1 Type-C Gen 2/TB3 --> USB-C 3.1 TB3 to HDMI cable --> #2 VH240a HDMI in

> [Src 1 - Lenovo Forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Connect-two-external-displays-to-T480S-without-doc/m-p/4155830)
>
> [Src 2 - Dell Forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/P2417H-Dual-Lenovo-T480-3-screens/td-p/6110788)